# how to maximize weekly revenue using profit function and derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives

p=45-0.01q where p is price of each product sold and q is the quantity of products sold.

a) find the quantity that maximizes the weekly revenue of the company

b) what price should the company sell each product for in order to maximize the weekly revenue

c) what is the maximum weekly revenue for the company?

I found the revenue function R=45q-0.01q^2 and the derivative of it R'=45-0.02q but don't know what to do next  or how to apply those

Answer (score 2):

Total Revenue $\equiv$ $TR = P \cdot Q = (45 - 0.01 \cdot Q) \cdot Q.$ 
Hence,

$TR = 45 \cdot Q - 0.01 \cdot Q^2$

Let Marginal Revenue $\equiv$ MR. Then,

$MR = \frac{\partial TR}{\partial Q}$ $= 45 -0.02 \cdot Q$

and set $MR= 0.00$ for a maximum.

Solving $[45 -0.02 \cdot Q = 0.00]$ we obtain $Q = 2,250$. Now, plug $Q=2,250$ into the Price formula: $P = (45 - 0.01 \cdot Q)$ and solve for $P$. Finally, use $P \cdot Q$ to determine the maximum revenue.